# SharePoint 2016 url redirect

Tags: 2016, iis

I have the following problem:
I use SharePoint 2016 and I have an own page inside this SharePoint environment.
It's basically structured the following way [www.foo.something.com/somenumber/](http://www.foo.something.com/somenumber/)
To make it easier for the users I would like to use the following construct
[www.bar.something.com](http://www.bar.something.com) which redirects to [www.foo.something.com/somenumber/](http://www.foo.something.com/somenumber/)
What would be the standard way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless [www.bar.something.com](http://www.bar.something.com) is already a SharePoint Web Application, what I would do is stand up one (or more for high availability) web servers (IIS, Apache, or a cloud-based service like an Azure Front Door) and implement an HTTP 301 redirect which will allow you to redirect requests to that URL to your target URL.

If it is a Web Application, you can place a JS snippet on the home page of that site in the master page or in the Script Editor Webpart.

```
window.location.replace("http://www.foo.something.com/somenumber/");
```